# How to make script to wait for given time span before executing next it block in protractor

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

Automating a test case, in which needed to fill a form containing 5 date picker and 30 fields. After filling the form need to invoke a jar which will pull the filled data from the DB and process it independently.

Note: jar does not return any value back to script however it is expected from the jar to update the process status on UI after 1 min.

Have tried wait in beforeEach() block, but it is causing unnecessary delay of the whole script as it is introducing wait before each steps.
In on of the thread in this forum, people suggested to use done function of Jasmine 2. But i don't understand how to use it.

Sample code:

```
describe("Test functionality of xyz", ()=>{
    // few it block
    it();
    it();

    //login to the UI 
    it("Login to application", ()=>{
        utility.signIn(inputTestdata.Common.LoginPage.Username, inputTestdata.Common.LoginPage.Password);
    });

    // filling the form 
    it("Fill the form", ()=>{
        utility.fill_form(dataSet);
    }); // wanted to make protractor should wait for specifically 1 min before executing the next it block

    it("Process the data", ()=>{
        utility.runSimulator();
    }); //wanted to wait here to for 2 min  

    it("Verify the result", ()=>{
        //verifying the result 
    });

    //some more it blocks 
});
```

Expected: Once it block of filling form is processed then only invoking jar it block should get executed. Then it wait for specified time before executing verification result step.

But actually, protractor call the form filling it block and immediate call the jar it block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned you don't want to wait after each 'it', you will have to wait within 'it' block.

you could use [sleep](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.sleep) or [wait](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait)
, depending on your situation

**Another way** is to have nested describe only for the test case where you want to wait. and add wait in `afterEach` method

Comment: Am using sleep and wait for making the browser to wait for specific time. But it does not stopping the protractor for immediate invocation of jar step. Is there any way I can put sleep or wait between two it blocks

Comment: If you check the specification, the sleep and wait method return promise.
You should `await browser.sleep(<<time>>)`

Answer (score 0):

You can hold the execution of the program by using "browser.sleep(time in milliseconds)".

```
describe("Test functionality of xyz", ()=>{
// few it block
it();
it();

//login to the UI 
it("Login to application", ()=>{
    utility.signIn(inputTestdata.Common.LoginPage.Username, 
    inputTestdata.Common.LoginPage.Password);
});

// filling the form 
it("Fill the form", ()=>{
    utility.fill_form(dataSet);
    browser.sleep(2000);// here you can specify how long you want to wait at this 
stage. 
}); // wanted to make protractor should wait for specifically 1 min before executing 
the next it block

it("Process the data", ()=>{
    utility.runSimulator();
    browser.sleep(2000); // here you can specify how long you want to wait at this 
    stage. 
}); //wanted to wait here to for 2 min  

it("Verify the result", ()=>{
    //verifying the result 
});

//some more it blocks 
});
```